# Get list of classes from array of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array that holds a number of `option` elements, depending on if it has the `hidden` class or not.

```
var list = $('#condition option').not('.hidden');
```

How can I get an array of classes these elements have?

What I have tried:

```
var list = $('#condition option').not('.hidden').attr('class');
```

However, this only returns classes associated with the last element in the array.

Comment: You just need to go through each item https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Can't you get `$('#condition option')` and loop through it like with `.each` as @Huangism said?

Comment: `let listOfClasses = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#condition option')).map(el => el.getAttribute('class')).filter(cls => !cls.match(/hidden/));` One liner, no jquery.

Comment: PLEASE stop adding the jQuery tag to your title. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use .map():

```
$('#condition option').not('.hidden').map(function() {
  return this.className.split(' ');
}).get();
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4oc6757/)

Comment: @noclist  Good one, But you should use something to avoid spaces. see my second example as i use `trim` and `/\s+/` to avoid spaces.
For example apply your code in this element `<option class="a     b c  ">` it will not work as expected .

Answer (score 0):

Like suggested in the comments, use JQuery's *each* function.

```
var list_condition = $('#condition option').not('.hidden');
var list_class = []; // Creates an empty array

$(list_condition).each(function(index) {
  list_class.push($(list_condition)[index].attr('class')); // Pushes the element into the array
});
```

Comment: Good, But you do not need to use `index` see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this. The list selects all of the dom elements. 
The `.each` iterates through them all.

```
var list = $('#condition option').not('.hidden').attr('class');
$(list).each(function( index ) {
  var myClass = $(this).attr("class"); 
  console.log(myClass);
});
```

Comment: `class` is a reserved  keyword. It's not recommended to use it as variable name.

Comment: Also you need to fix the last line inside the function `console.log(class);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/JQuery.each/) function

**Example:**

```js
var list = $('#condition option').not('.hidden'),
    classes = [];

$(list).each(function () {
  classes.push($(this).attr('class'));
});
    
console.log(classes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="condition">
   <option class="some-class-1" > some option </option>
   <option class="some-class-2" > some option </option>
   <option class="some-class-3" > some option </option>
   <option class="some-class-4" > some option </option>
   <option class="some-class-5" > some option </option>
   <option class="some-class-6" > some option </option>
   <option class="some-class-7" > some option </option>
   <option class="some-class-8" > some option </option>
</select>
```

**Update**

If you want to split/separate every single element, for example if some `option` have some classes like `class-1-a`, `class-1-b` .. etc

in this case you may need [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

**Example**

```js
var list = $('#condition option').not('.hidden'),
    allClasses = [];

$(list).each(function () {
  var elemClasses = $(this).attr('class');
    elemClasses.trim().split(/\s+/).map(function (x) {
        allClasses.push(x);      
    })
  
});

console.log(allClasses);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="condition">
   <option class="some-class-1-a        some-class-1-b" > some option </option>
   <option class="some-class-2-a some-class-1-b " > some option </option>
   <option class="some-class-3" > some option </option>
   <option class="some-class-4" > some option </option>
   <option class="some-class-5" > some option </option>
   <option class="some-class-6" > some option </option>
   <option class="some-class-7" > some option </option>
   <option class="some-class-8" > some option </option>
</select>
```